# How to change a pattern like XX1/XXSomething/XX1/Something to XXSomething/XX1/Something in perl

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching, file-handling, regex-negation

I'm having a file in which some lines have some patterns like

```
M1/XX2/XX1 XX2/XX1/XX2/WCLKB XX2/XX1/XX2/P001  
M1/XX4/XX5 XX4/XX5/XX4/WCLKB XX4/XX5/XX4/P001
```

Here in some patterns XX2 is repeating. I need to change the above line to

```
M1/XX2/XX1 XX1/XX2/WCLKB XX1/XX2/P001
M1/XX4/XX5 XX5/XX4/WCLKB XX5/XX4/P001
```

These XX can vary  XX[0..9] 
The code is in Perl.

I tried using some regex but was confused.

```
 open(FILE,$FilePath);
 @linesInFile = <FILE>;
 close(FILE);
 foreach $item(@linesInFile){
    if(grep(/^XX?\/XX.\/XX)
  #I dont know how to complete this 
}
```

Comment: Being a new SO user, I'll suggest you to please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and specifically [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it helps others and in turn they can help you back, else your post may be downvoted (although I didn't downvote your post) and closed.

Comment: So if a words starts with `XX[0..9]/` you want to delete that part from the word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking specifically for `XXn/XXm/XXn/` (where `n` is the same number both times), you can use backreferences:

```
s{(XX[0-9]+/)(XX[0-9]+/\1)}{$2}g
```

Here `\1` refers back to and matches the same string as the first capturing group, `(XX[0-9]+/)`.

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/imqtB0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = readline DATA) {
    $line =~ s{(XX[0-9]+/)(XX[0-9]+/\1)}{$2}g;
    print $line;
}

__DATA__
M1/XX2/XX1 XX2/XX1/XX2/WCLKB XX2/XX1/XX2/P001
M1/XX4/XX5 XX4/XX5/XX4/WCLKB XX4/XX5/XX4/P001
```

Output:

```
M1/XX2/XX1 XX1/XX2/WCLKB XX1/XX2/P001
M1/XX4/XX5 XX5/XX4/WCLKB XX5/XX4/P001
```

Comment: We might also consider using `\b` word boundaries in our regexes! Anyway +1.

Comment: Note that this changes `ZXX1/XX2/XX1/b` into `ZXX2/XX1/b`

Answer (score 1):

If it's ok to blindly remove the first part:

```
while (<>) {
   s{ \K[^\s/]+/}{}g;
   print;
}
```

As a one-liner:

```
perl -pe's{ \K[^\s/]+/}{}g'
```

---

If you want to make sure it matches the pattern you specified:

```
while (<>) {
   s{(?<!\S)(XX\d)/(?=XX[^\s/]+/\1/\S)}{}ag;
   print;
}
```

As a one-liner:

```
perl -pe's{(?<!\S)(XX\d)/(?=XX[^\s/]+/\1/\S)}{}ag'
```

The key is `\1`, means which means "match what the first capture captured".

Comment: The first one matches every word that contains a slash (but does not start with a slash), and removes the part before (and including) the first slash.

Comment: @melpomene, Yes. That's what's meant by "blindly removing the first part".

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have explained in the description of your problem `XX[0..9]`, the following `perl` command should do the trick:

**Input:**

```
$ cat input
M1/XX2/XX1 XX2/XX1/XX2/WCLKB XX2/XX1/XX2/P001  
M1/XX4/XX5 XX4/XX5/XX4/WCLKB XX4/XX5/XX4/P001
```

**Command:**

```
perl -pe 's@\bXX(\d)/XX(\d)/XX\1@XX$2/XX$1@g' input
```

**Output:**

```
M1/XX2/XX1 XX1/XX2/WCLKB XX1/XX2/P001  
M1/XX4/XX5 XX5/XX4/WCLKB XX5/XX4/P001
```

Comment: That should be `$2` and `$1` in the replacement part (see also `perl -w`).

Comment: Note that (by default) `\d` matches more than just `[0-9]`. It matches any Unicode character with the "digit" property.

Comment: @melpomene: thanks I have edited my answer accordingly. And indeed `[0-9]` might be safer in this contest.

Comment: @melpomene, Re "*Note that (by default) `\d` matches more than just `[0-9]`.*", Unless you use `-CI` (or equivalent) or `use feature qw( unicode_strings );` (or equivalent) or `/u` (or equivalent), it won't. And it can easily be forced to match only 0-9 using `/a`.

Comment: @ikegami: thank you for picking this up! I have edited my answer by adding a positive lookbehind, thank you also for editing! The rest is a matter how we interpret the question

Comment: @ikegami: yeah just simply go for `\b` :-)

Comment: @ikegami That depends entirely on where the strings you're matching against are coming from. If those strings contain Unicode digits (codepoints beyond 255), they are necessarily encoded using UTF-8 internally, which in turn forces `/u` behavior. Of course that doesn't apply if you're dealing with a pure ASCII string, but in that case you don't have to worry about Unicode character classes anyway.

Comment: @ikegami As for `/a`, that's only available from 5.14 on. `unicode_strings` was introduced in 5.12. And as mentioned above, in older Perl versions `\d` will always match Unicode digits.

Comment: Re "*That depends entirely on where the strings you're matching against are coming from*", We know where they're coming from (`ARGV`). That's why I said "*Unless you use `-CI` (or equivalent)*" (though that should have been `-CIi`).

Comment: Re "*`unicode_strings` was introduced in 5.12.*", Then it's easy to not use it :)

Comment: Re "*As for `/a`, that's only available from 5.14 on.*", Very few people use older versions at this point.